Are All Rules mentioned in scriptures come collectively under Law of Karma?
Namasthe.
Is there any Laws apart from the Law of Karma?
Are all Laws and rules mentioned in Scriptures work independently as seperate individual laws?
OR
All the rules mentioned in scriptures regarding different punishments for various sins and different rules mentioned in scriptures come collectively under the Law of Karma itself ?
